# Problema con regexp al usar .*"

Tags: html, python, regex

Estoy usando el módulo re para extraer datos de una web. Concretemente: https://thepiratebay.org/search/piratas%20del%20caribe

Pero tengo un problema, si hago:

```
re.findall('<a href="(.*)"', data)
```

Me devuelve desde el inicio del href hasta el final de data.
Si hago:

```
re.findall('<a href="(.*)" class', a)
```

Entonces sí me devuelve el valor correcto.
Yo quiero seleccionar todo desde la primera comilla del href hasta la segunda, pero si pongo una comilla después del .* parece que lo ignora. En cambio con texto normal sí funciona.

Concretamente quiero obtener el nombre de los resultados, y el magnet link. Lo intento así:

```
re.findall("""<div class="detName"><a href=".*" .*">(.*)</a>.*href="(magnet.*)" title="Download thi""", html.replace('\n', ''))
```

Y así (para ver sólo los nombres, sólo era una prueba):

```
re.findall("""<div class="detName"><a href=".*" .*">(.*)</a>""", data.replace('\n', ''))
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
['<img src="//thepiratebay.org/static/img/rss_small.gif" alt="RSS" />']
```

¿Cómo debería hacerlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es, en lugar de buscar cualquier carácter después de `href="`, es buscar cualquier carácter que no sea `"`:

```
 re.findall('<a href="([^"]*)"', data)
```

Otra opción es buscar el número mínimo de caracteres que cumplan la condición utilizando `?`:

```
re.findall('<a href="(.*?)"', data)
```